# Classes with JPA @MappedSuperclass use a lot of memory

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Our project uses micro-services and JPA.

In order to manage the DB models centrally and share the models to each service, we defined each model as an abstract class with `@MappedSuperclass` annotation and assembled them into a separate jar. Each service can import this jar, and uses the models that it needs.

There are about **400** models in this jar.

We found that:

- If service imports this model jar, it requires an additional **600MB** memory after startup.
- If I remove this jar or remove all `@MappedSuperclass`, memory usage is normal after startup.

Service uses spring boot 1.5.13.RELEASE and eclipselink 2.7.4/2.7.6. The *eclipselink.weaving* is **static**.

I don't know why those models were loaded into memory and who did this loading, although they are not used.

And how to resolve this problem. Or do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

A example of user in model jar:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @Column(name = "\"GUID\"", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String guid;

    @Column(name = "\"Name\"", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "\"Age\"")
    private Integer age;

    public String getGuid()
    {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(String guid)
    {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    ......
}
```

Service uses this user model likes

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ADMIN_USER")
public class AdminUser extends User
{
     ....
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Why do you use MappedSuperclass?

Comment: I edited and appended an example code. MappedSuperclass can applied its mapping class information to the entities that inherit from it, and has no separate table defined for the mapped super class. If no MappedSuperclass, the JPA can not get mapping info, which defined in super class, from the inherited entity.